# Clojure zipper to remove all right siblings

Tags: clojure, functional-programming, zipper

I want to write a function for a zipper that removes all right siblings of a node while staying at the same location.

```
(defn remove-all-rights-1 [loc]
  (if (zip/right loc) 
    (recur (zip/remove (zip/right loc)))
    loc))
```

The problem here is that [remove](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.zip/remove) returns the location that would have preceded the current node in DFS.

Therefore the following example...

```
(-> (clojure.zip/vector-zip [1 [[2] 3]])
    (zip/down)
    (zip/right)
    (zip/down)
    (remove-all-rights-1)
    (zip/replace :x)
    (zip/root))
```

...gives `[1 [[:x]]]` instead of `[1 [:x]]` because `zip/remove` jumped to the bottom leaf instead of just going back left.

How should I remove the right siblings without also *changing location in the tree*? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(letfn [(kill-right [loc]
            (let [lost   (zip/rights loc)
                  parent (-> loc zip/up zip/node)
                  node   (into (empty parent) (take (- (count parent) (count lost)) parent))]
                (-> loc
                    zip/up
                    (zip/replace node)
                    zip/down
                    zip/rightmost)))]
    (-> (clojure.zip/vector-zip [1 [[2] 3]])
        zip/down
        zip/right
        zip/down
        kill-right
        (zip/replace :x)
        zip/root))
```

Answer (score 2):

Generalizing [akond's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55352656/1062189) gave the following solution:

```
(defn remove-all-rights
  "Removes all right siblings. Stays at original location."
  [loc]
  (let [parent-loc (zip/up loc)
        |lefts| (inc (count (zip/lefts loc)))]
    (->> (zip/make-node loc (zip/node parent-loc) (take |lefts| (zip/children parent-loc)))
         (zip/replace parent-loc)
         (zip/down)
         (zip/rightmost))))
```

The main idea is to construct a copy of the parent node where the collection of children does not contain the right siblings.

Answer (score 1):

This can be easily accomplished with the Tupelo Forest library:

```
(dotest
  (with-forest (new-forest)
    (let [edn-orig          [1 [[2] 3]]
          root-hid          (add-tree (edn->tree edn-orig))
          hid               (find-hid root-hid [::tf/list ::tf/list])
          subtree-edn-orig  (-> hid hid->tree tree->edn)
          >>                (kids-update hid butlast)
          subtree-edn-final (-> hid hid->tree tree->edn)
          edn-final         (-> root-hid hid->tree tree->edn)]

      (is= subtree-edn-orig      [[2] 3])
      (is= subtree-edn-final     [[2]])
      (is= edn-final          [1 [[2]]]  ))))
```

The tree created has nodes with `:tag` values of `:tupelo.forest/list` at the first & second levels:

```
  (is= (hid->bush root-hid)
    [{:tag :tupelo.forest/list, :tupelo.forest/index nil}
     [#:tupelo.forest{:value 1, :index 0}]
     [{:tag :tupelo.forest/list, :tupelo.forest/index 1}
      [{:tag :tupelo.forest/list, :tupelo.forest/index 0}
       [#:tupelo.forest{:value 2, :index 0}]]]] )
```

An HID is a pointer to a tree node, so `root-hid` points to the root node of the tree and `hid` points to the subtree `[[2] 3]`.  After we remove the right-most node `3`, `hid` points to the subtree `[[2]]`.

For the child nodes (`kids`), we use the `butlast` function to remove the right-most, then convert the data from a forest/tree format back into EDN.

See [the README here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/docs/forest.adoc), and the [API docs here](https://cloojure.github.io/doc/tupelo/tupelo.forest.html#var-kids-update).  There are also many [live code examples here](https://github.com/cloojure/tupelo/blob/master/test/clj/tst/tupelo/forest_examples.clj).  Also see the [Clojure Conj video](https://youtu.be/RtavTnRr0oM).